# Strikethrough in markdown codeblock github/gitlab

Tags: markdown, gitlab, github-flavored-markdown

I have an issue on using `strikethrough` in markdown `codeblock`.

I can normally add the strike through using two tilde `~~` in the normal markdown, but when i write the strikethrough in codeblock i can only see `~~strikethough~~` and not <s>strikethrough</s>.

Example:

**Should be:**

> Theory 1 : <s>Some theory part that is irrelevant now but was relevant
>   some time ago</s> New theory part added later.

**Output as:**

> Theory 1 : ~~Some theory part that is irrelevant now but was relevant
>   some time ago~~ New theory part added later.

I cannot find the usage inside the code block on the markdown.

**Is it possible to `strikethrough` inside `codeblock` or is it not yet supported.?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strikethrough code in markdown on github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395000/strikethrough-code-in-markdown-on-github)

Comment: no, markdown is not interpreted inside codeblocks. you can always use inline/raw-html instead of codeblocks though..

Answer (score 3):

use `<del>xyz</del>`

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
<del>something-to-strike-through
```

This will work until the next line break char in your text. i.e. block texts are also supported. And it will stop once you put a line break (ENTER).